# $M = A+B$ made up of symmetric and skew symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Show that every square matrix $M$ can be expressed as the sum $M=A+B$ where $A$ is a symmetric matrix and $B$ is a skew symmetric matrix.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix

Answer (score 3):

$$A = \frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)+\frac{1}{2}(A-A^T).$$
The first of these is symmetric, the second skew-symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

What properties does the matrix $M+{}^{\mathrm t\!}M$ have?